# Dynamic retrieve json element .NET 6

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-6.0

I want to retrieve a single value from a json string.

Previously I used `Newtonsoft` like this:

```
var jsonString = @"{ ""MyProp"" : 5 }";
dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        
Console.WriteLine(obj["MyProp"].ToString());
```

But I can't seem to get it to work in .NET 6:

I've tried this so far:

```
var jsonString = @"{ ""MyProp"" : 5 }";
dynamic obj = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
        
Console.WriteLine(obj.MyProp.ToString());
```

which results in this error:

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement.this[int]' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You could just use NewtonSoft.Json in .NET 6, too.

Comment: Oh, --- that is a good point...  I have been asked "just to use the framework's one", hence my question, but indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading upon this [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31175), I had success using this approach:

> NET 6 will include the JsonNode type which can be used to serialize and deserialize dynamic data.

Trying it results in:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = @"{ ""MyProp"" : 5 }";
        //parse it
        var myObject = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
        //retrieve the value
        var myProp= myObject.RootElement
                            .GetProperty("MyProp");
        
        Console.WriteLine(myProp);
    }
}
```

Which seems to work in my case.

---

As by @robnick's comment - you can also chain `GetProperty` to get nested properties of the data structure.

```
var quote = rootElement.GetProperty("contents")
                       .GetProperty("quotes")[0]
                       .GetProperty("quote")
                       .GetString();
```

Comment: Keep in mind, as nvoigt mentioned, you can still use `NewtonSoft`; for me this was just a project requirement.

Comment: You can also chain the .GetProperty() methods if you have nested JSON, example: .GetProperty("contents").GetProperty("quotes")[0].GetProperty("quote").GetString()

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else comes across this while searching on the subject...

If you parse as a JSON node directly, you can get your data in a single GetValue.

Example (using explicit types for clarity and '!' to handle nulls):

```
JsonNode? jnode = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString);
string quote = jnode["contents"]!["quotes"]!.AsArray()[0]!["quote"]!.GetValue<string>();
```